# Does thermal state in Rindler spacetime correspond to Minkowski vacuum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect

We know that the Minkowski vacuum corresponds to the thermal state in a Rindler wedge at Unruh temp. But does the thermal state in one Rindler wedge at Unruh temperature uniquely map to the Minkowski vacuum? Or could there be other states 
 in the Minkowski space field theory which also corresponds to thermal state in one of the wedges? In other words, If I am doing field theory in say the left Rindler wedge and the state is specified to be thermal at Unruh temp, does it mean that the state in the Minkowski space field theory is the vacuum, or could it be something else?

One class of states it would map to are the following: $$U_R|0\rangle$$
where $U_R$ denotes an unitary operator in the right Rindler wedge. But it's not clear that they correspond to nice Minkowski states. Are there other states in Minkowski space field theory that, on writing in the Rindler basis and tracing out degrees of freedom from one wedge, would yield the thermal state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OON's idea can be made more precise to obtain an example of state which is identical to Minkowski vacuum in the left Rindler wedge but is different in the right wedge.

It is just matter of a correct  choice  of the local operator in OON's idea. The idea works only with certain local operators: *isometries* localized in the right wedge.

Take a real  smooth function $g$ whose  support is included in the (open) right  wedge. Consider the  *unitary* operator (though an isometry would be sufficient)
$$U(g) := e^{i \phi(g)}\tag{1},$$
where I assumed that the field operator $\phi(g)$ is selfadjoint (it is essentially selfadjoint so actually $\phi(g)$ in the exponent is the closure of it).  From  *Weyl commutation relations* and *Stone theorem*, 
$$U(g) \phi(f) =\phi(f)U(g)\tag{2}$$
if $f$ and $g$ have spatially separated supports as it happens in particular if $f$ has support in the left wedge.

Define  $$\Omega_g := U_g\Omega$$ where $\Omega$ is Minkowski vacuum. It is clear that $\Omega_g$ is still a unit vector and  is different from $\Omega$ if $g\neq 0$. Regarding *Wightman functions* of the new state,  (2) implies that 
$$\langle \Omega_g| \phi(f_1)\cdots  \phi(f_n)\Omega_g \rangle= \langle \Omega| U_g^*\phi(f_1)\cdots  \phi(f_n)U_g\Omega \rangle = \langle \Omega| \phi(f_1)\cdots  \phi(f_n)U_g^*U_g\Omega \rangle 
= \langle \Omega| \phi(f_1)\cdots  \phi(f_n)\Omega \rangle$$
if each $f_k$ has support in the left wedge. There $\Omega$ and $\Omega_g$ are not distinguishable. In particular $\Omega_g$ has the same thermal properties as $\Omega$ with respect to the Killing boost  (it satisfies the KMS condition due to Bisognano-Wickmann theorem).

In the right wedge, $\Omega_g$ is a *coherent state* in view of its definition.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are infinite number of states with reduced density for the left wedge being in thermal state while the total state is not the Minkowski vacuum. To obtain the latter the reduced density matrix in the right state should alsobbe in the thermal state AND there also should be a specific entanglement between wedges.

Among nice Minkowski states you may consider e.g.
$$
|\psi\rangle= \int_{\Omega_R} d^4x \mathcal{O}(x)|0\rangle
$$
where $\mathcal{O}$ is a local operator and $\Omega_R$ is restricted to the right wedge. Any state of this type will have the same thermal state for the reduced density matrix of the left wedge.

Note that the same reduced density matrix means that observables restricted to the left wedge can't distinguish those states.

The meaning of all this is very simple. No signal passes from one wedge to another. Thus having information only about one wedge is not enough to reconstruct the state of the quantun field in the whole spacetime.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had thought, but how does one explicitly show that the reduced density matrix for that state is thermal?

Comment: Reduced density matrix is $$\sum_{E^{"} }\phantom{E} _R\langle E"|\psi\rangle \langle \psi| E"\rangle_R= \sum_{E",E',E} e^{-\beta (E+E')/2)}\phantom{E} _R\langle E"|\mathcal{O}(x)|E\rangle_R \phantom{E}_R \langle E'|O(x)|E"\rangle_R |E\rangle_L \phantom{E}_L \langle E| $$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: I think I got it: by taking the spectral decomposition of the operator $\mathcal{O}(x)$ and then tracing over its eigenstates instead of the energy eigenstates. Are there other ways to show this?

Comment: I do not think your answer is correct. You are saying in particular that $\langle \Omega| \phi(f)\phi(f) \phi(g)\phi(g) \Omega \rangle/ \langle \Omega|\phi(g)\phi(g) \Omega \rangle = \langle \Omega| \phi(f)\phi(f) \Omega \rangle$ if $f$ and $g$ have supports spacelike-separated. $f$ supported in the left wedge and $g$ in the right wedge. $\Omega$ is Minkowski vacuum.

Comment: Well, Wick theorem proves that the left-hand side of the identity above is the right hand side with the further addend  $\langle \Omega| \phi(f)\phi(g) \Omega \rangle/ \langle \Omega|\phi(g)\phi(g) \Omega \rangle$. So what we should to prove is that $ \langle \Omega| \phi(f)\phi(g) \Omega \rangle=0$

Comment: You can define $f(x)$ as $g(x+r)$ for sufficiently large spacelike  $r$. In other words you are saying that this function $r \mapsto  \langle \Omega| \phi(f)U_r\phi(f) \Omega \rangle$ vanishes if $r$ is sufficiently large. I am not sure (I have not time to compute it) but I think that that function is analytic... So it should vanish everywhere.  It does not make sense, since it cannot vanish at $r=0$. Perhaps I am wrong, but I cannot see how you can say that $\langle \Omega| \phi(f)\phi(g) \Omega \rangle=0$ if the supports of the functions are spacelike separated.

Comment: I expect that it is true in the limit of  supports infinitely far to each other, but I am not sure that it is true if they are simply spacelike separated...

Comment: Without reference to analytic functions  $\langle \Omega| \phi(f)U_r\phi(f) \Omega \rangle$ is something like $\int_{\mathbb R^3} |\hat{f}(\vec{k})|^2 e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} d\vec{k}/k^0$. It does not vanish also for large $\vec{r}$, when supports of $f(x)$ and $f(x+ \vec{r})$ are surely spacelike separated. It vanishes as $\vec{r}$ diverges in view of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. Your claim,  as it stands,  is false.

Comment: The point is that, it is true that no signal may pass from a wedge to another, but $\Omega$ the vacuum state is a non-local object. ...Think of Reeh-Schlieder property for instance.

Comment: @ValterMoretti ok, I'll check myself and answer but few hours later

Comment: @ONN Be sure that I have understood well your claim: you says that, for instance $\phi(g)|\Omega\rangle$ is identical to $|\Omega\rangle$ when $g$ is supported in the right wedge and local measurements (Wightman functions) are performed in the left wedge. Do I have understood well?

Comment: @ValterMoretti Seems right and also I think you are right about its validity. So please hold on, I'll probably rewrite it with more correct statements later

Comment: @OON  Physically of course, acting on the vacuum with a field operator does not have any physical meaning. The argument that any operation done in one wedge doesn't affect measurements in others would translate to acting on the vacuum with unitary operators that act only on one wedge. They could corresp to adding a perturbation to the Hamiltonian that creates particles locally in the right wedge. Of course these would leave the left wedge measurements the same. I suppose that's what you want.

Comment: @NirmalayaKajuri I think there's more general set of states of this sort than just with unitary transform of one wedge. Anyway there are a lot of nasty states like $\rho_L\otimes\rho_R$ that can't be obtained simply by such unitary transform but have singularities on horizons. I'll try to reflect all this tomorrow - too tired right now :(((

Comment: Yes, but those are not valid states in Minkowski space field theory. Indeed, my question is if there are more general states in the Mink. space field theory than those that can be obtained by unitary transformations. Let me know your thoughts :)